# Ошибка: OSЕrror: [WinError 10049] Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
colorama.init()

def main():
    host = "193.151.234.81"
    port = 5552 # порт
 
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))
 
    s.listen(1)
    print(Fore.RED + "Listening port 5552")
    connection, address = s.accept()
    print(Fore.WHITE + "Connection  " + str(address))
    while True:
        try:
            print(Fore.BLUE)
            toSend = input("windows@windows:  ")
            connection.send(toSend.encode())
            data = connection.recv(1024).decode()
            print(data)
        except:
            break
    print("Connection refused")
    connection.close()
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: А "193.151.234.81" - это у вас локальный адрес?

Comment: Нет, но я уже решил проблему

Answer (score 0):

Делайте бинд на "0.0.0.0" и проброс порта на роутере если есть роутер